Cut object and change length
I am a beginner at blender. What would be the easiest method to delete the phone holder and decrease the length of the arm? I can look up more into the method (or the steps) by my own I just need some guidance.


The topology here scares me, if the phone holder is a cylindrical part and connected to everything else, I could only use manual selection...

@KISKAart No the phone holder is not the cylindrical part. That is the cup holder. Maybe it just easier to start from scratch to achieve what I want then to modify an existing model?

It is probably easier to redo the model, I would start with a low poly cylinder and carefully place edge loops where you need them. I think there were several objects with boolean modifiers here. You can find some good topology tutorials online.
